# Ember Component Bindings Not Propagating

Tags: ember.js

I'm expirencing some weirdness with Ember components. First problem I'm seeing is that class attribute binding is not working. I'm also witnessing properties some how being unbound after the first time they are mutated. This is just a simple tabs component that I am building. Here's a repro http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uDUfONi/2/edit

JS

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectedTab: '',

  initialTab: function () {
    var name = this.get( 'model' ).get('firstObject');
    this.set( 'selectedTab', name );
    return name;
  }.property()

});


App.MyTabComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  isSelected: false,

  tabChanged: function () {
    if ( this.get( 'selectedTab' ) !== this.get( 'name' ) ) {
      this.set( 'isSelected', false );
    } else {
      this.set( 'isSelected', true );
    }
  }.observes('selectedTab'),

  checkInitialTab: function () { 
    if ( this.get( 'initialTab' ) === this.get( 'name' ) ) {
      this.set( 'isSelected', true);
    } else {
      this.set( 'isSelected', false );
    }
  }.on( 'didInsertElement' ),

  actions: {
    selectTab: function () {
      if ( this.get( 'selectedTab' ) !== this.get( 'name' ) ) {
        this.set( 'selectedTab',  this.get( 'name' ) );
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Templates

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">


    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">


    {{my-tabs model=model initialTab=initialTab selectedTab=selectedTab}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/my-tabs">
  Selected Tab: {{selectedTab}}
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    {{my-tab name="control" initialTab=initialTab selectedTab=selectedTab}}
    {{#each item in model}}
      {{my-tab name=item initialTab=controller.initialTab selectedTab=controller.selectedTab}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>

  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/my-tab">
    <li {{action selectTab name}} {{bind-attr class="isSelected:active"}}>
    {{isSelected}}
      <a href="#">{{name}}</a>
    </li>

  </script>
```

Comment: I'm looking into it, something is going crazy with bind-attr, it works fine when you strip it out, but it's somehow breaking it along the way with it in... http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uDUfONi/3/edit

Comment: Yea it's really weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, had to consult with another Emberino on this one.

It came down to the fact that there were nested li element.  When you defined the tagName on the component it injects the component with that tag.  Unfortunately it was breaking ember/html/somewhere/Idunno.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uDUfONi/10/edit

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/my-tab">
  <a>{{name}}</a>
</script>

App.MyTabComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  classNameBindings: ['isSelected:active', ':clickable'],
  isSelected: function(){
    return this.get('selectedTab') === this.get('name');
  }.property('selectedTab', 'name'),

  click: function () {
    this.set('selectedTab', this.get('name'));
  }

});
```

instead of the li being defined twice:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/my-tab2">
  <li {{action selectTab name}}>
   {{isSelected}}
   <a href>{{name}}</a>
  </li>
</script>

App.MyTabComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  .....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's definitely the double `li` that is *somehow* breaking things.  I have no idea exactly how...

I just commented out the `tagName : 'li',` line and the `{{isSelected}}` value in the template starts showing the right thing.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uDUfONi/12/edit